# How can i make tabs active dynamically

Tags: php, html

I have a side tab for my website which i want to reuse for all my pages, so i created a template for the tab called 'tab.php' and then required the 'tab.php' in all my pages so that i can easily reuse it. But i also have a class named active, which indicates which tab you are currently on. Since am using a single tab file for all my pages, how can i change the active tab based on the tab a user is currently on.

This is the tab file

```
              <div class="ms_nav_wrapper">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="index.php" class="active" title="Discover">
                        <span class="nav_icon">
                            <span class="icon icon_discover"></span>
                        </span>
                        <span class="nav_text">
                            discover
                        </span>
                        </a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="Users.php" title="Users">
                        <span class="nav_icon">
                            <span class="icon icon_users"></span>
                        </span>
                        <span class="nav_text">
                            users
                        </span>
                        </a>
                        </li>
                       
                        <li><a href="genres.php" title="Genres">
                        <span class="nav_icon">
                            <span class="icon icon_genres"></span>
                        </span>
                        <span class="nav_text">
                            genres
                        </span>
                        </a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="top_track.php" title="Top Tracks">
                        <span class="nav_icon">
                            <span class="icon icon_tracks"></span>
                        </span>
                        <span class="nav_text">
                            top tracks
                        </span>
                        </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
             </div
```

Answer (score 0):

First Define the page name

$pg = basename(substr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],0,strrpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],'.')));

after that each and every li class look  like this placed

```
<li class="<?= ($pg == 'index') ? 'active':''; ?>">
```